# Deep Link in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, deep-linking

I got a link from another developer , my requirement is to open the app if that is already installed otherwise redirect to the app store. But its always redirecting me to the app store. It does not open already installed app. Can you guys please tell me how can i fix it and do i need to add something in my info.plist to call deep link . I am sharing code here suggest what should i have to do . 
[image]

Comment: It seems that you are trying to open another app from your own app - is that correct?

Comment: yes its correct

Comment: did the other developer confirmed that he implemented deep linking correctly?

Comment: Unfortunately, He is on leave and could not contact him . He located in another office. a big gap of communication :(

Answer (score 1):

You must add the url that you check in your code in the plist of the app you want to open

Suppose you want to open App2 from App1

then add this to plist of App2

```
  <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
 <array>
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
    <string>com.TestApp</string>
    <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>testApp.linking</string>
    </array>
</dict>
```

in App1 check

```
 if(![[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"testApp.linking://?"]]){
     UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"App is not available!" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];

    }
```

take note of **testApp.linking** is same

Comment: You are right probably , but i do not have access to other developer and project to know about the scheme he used in app .I just have this link which i attached in my description . So could be the case that i can use the same link in App1 .

Comment: yes , you can't open another app if this setting doesn't exists in his plist

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are trying to open another app from your own app - I believe what you are doing is correct way to handle it. If the link does not work properly, it leads me to believe that the other app does not support deep linking correctly. In that case you need to contact the other developer and tell him to fix it.

To confirm this, you can try to open that link in safari on your device and it should redirect you to the app if it is configured correctly. If it does not redirect you there from the safari app, then it means that the other developer has some work to do.

Comment: yes exactly i tried to open this link in safari as well , its again redirecting me to app store , Although the app is already installed. Ok then i try to talk with another developer. Thanks